# Spring Jpa Specification filter by descendants of parent entity

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm trying to build a JPA specification to be able to filter on a WebPackageRefer refer -column.

The hierarchy is as follows. AbstractWebPackage is the most basic class, which has two descendants - UserWebPackage and WebPackage. In turn, WebPackage has an internal field created with the help of composition - WebPackageTemplateHistory. In turn, the necessary field that needs to be searched using the specification is contained in the WebPackageTemplateHistory and UserWebPackage entities and the name of this field is WebPackageRefer refer.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "ABSTRACT_WEB_PACKAGE")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "AWP_TYPE")
@AttributeOverride(name = "version", column = @Column(name = "AWP_VERSION"))
public abstract class AbstractWebPackage extends AbstractEntity {
...
}
 
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("TEMPLATE_BASED")
@SecondaryTable(name = "WEB_PACKAGE", pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "WP_AWP_ID"))
public class WebPackage extends AbstractWebPackage {
 
  @ManyToOne(targetEntity = WebPackageTemplateHistory.class)
  @JoinColumn(name = "WP_WPTH_ID", table = "WEB_PACKAGE")
  private WebPackageTemplateHistory webPackageTemplateHistory;
...
}
 
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("USER_BASED")
@SecondaryTable(
name = "USER_WEB_PACKAGE",
pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "UWP_AWP_ID")
)
public class UserWebPackage extends AbstractWebPackage {

  @Column(name = "UWP_REFER", table = "USER_WEB_PACKAGE", nullable = false)
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private WebPackageRefer refer;
...
}
 
@Entity
@Table(name = "WEB_PACKAGE_TEMPLATE_HISTORY")
@AttributeOverride(name = "version", column = @Column(name = "WPTH_VERSION"))
public class WebPackageTemplateHistory extends AbstractEntity {
        
  @Column(name = "WPTH_RELEVANT", nullable = false)
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  protected WebPackageRefer refer;
...
}
```

My question is, how can I write a specification so that it is generalized by the AbstractWebPackage class and can filter values by the WebPackageRefer refer field, which is located in two entities WebPackageTemplateHistory and UserWebPackage?